# How to use build timestamp in Visual Studios post build script

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

When building a project in Visual Studio at the Release target, I want to copy my binaries to a release folder which is under version control.
To easily recognize the build time, a timestamp file in the form

`__yyyy-MM-ddTHHmmss__`

should be added.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I used the following:

At the beginning of my project file I added a timestamp property:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>

    <Timestamp>$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd\THHmmss"))</Timestamp>

    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
```

Then one can use a postbuild event with `$(Timestamp)`:

```
<PostBuildEvent>
    if $(ConfigurationName) == Production (

    mkdir "$(SolutionDir)__RELEASE__\$(TargetName)"
    del /q "$(SolutionDir)__RELEASE__\$(TargetName)\*"

    echo $(Timestamp)&gt; "$(SolutionDir)__RELEASE__\$(TargetName)\__$(Timestamp)__"

    copy /Y "$(TargetDir)" "$(SolutionDir)__RELEASE__\$(TargetName)\"
    del /q "$(SolutionDir)__RELEASE__\$(TargetName)\*.tmp"
    del /q "$(SolutionDir)__RELEASE__\$(TargetName)\*.log"
    del /q "$(SolutionDir)__RELEASE__\$(TargetName)\*.err"

    TortoiseProc /command:add /path:"$(SolutionDir)__RELEASE__\"
  )
</PostBuildEvent>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody stumbles across this question, this did the trick for me:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Time>$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString())</Time>
</PropertyGroup>
<Message Text="$(Time2)" Importance="High" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is still looking for this, typing Time /T in the Post-build event command line works well.